# Como colocar ORDER BY no INNER JOIN/GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

Em um chat, preciso dar um SELECT nos contatos do usuário logado, mas os ordenando pela data das mensagens
O código está assim:

```
SELECT contatos.*, contas.Key_User, contas.Login_User, chat.Date 
FROM contatos INNER JOIN contas 
ON (contatos.Key_User1 = contas.Key_User) 
INNER JOIN chat 
ON (contatos.Key_User1 = chat.Key_User1 OR contatos.Key_User1 = chat.Key_User2) 
WHERE contas.Key_User not like 'valor'
GROUP BY contas.Key_User 
ORDER BY chat.Date DESC
```

E o resultado é esse: [image: Resultado do SELECT]. Mas o chat.Date apresentado é o da primeira mensagem, e não funciona porque pra ordenar por data recente, tem que ser justamente o contrário. Eu queria saber como faz pro GROUP BY pegar pela última mensagem.

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi o problema está no chat, e não no retorno do banco? pois no banco ele mostra primeiro a ultima mensagem, pois esta com DESC depois do ORDER BY, qual o problema no chat? não poderia ser o código dele

Comment: É o seguinte, quando eu dou o Select sem o GROUP BY, ele mostra todas as mensagens em DESC no chat.Date, perfeito, mas fazendo aparecer o mesmo contato várias vezes para cada mensagem que tem. Com o GROUP BY, ele aparece somente uma vez o contato, mas o problema é que usa o chat.Date do primeiro registro da mensagem, então ele vai usar como parâmetro de ordenação a data da primeira mensagem, e não da última.

Comment: Consegui! Eu substitui chat.Date por max(chat.Date) e foi.

Comment: @ErickGermani coloque a sua solução como resposta então, para ajudar outras pessoas e poder fechar a pergunta.

Comment: Removi a tag php, porque não tem nenhuma necessidade de relacionar uma única variável  com a linguagem php. Isso vai ampliar o horizonte de pessoas para te auxiliar, acredite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, você quer listar os usuários com base na data da ultima mensagem, tente utilizar com uma subconsulta, segue exemplo:

```
    SELECT 
         contatos.*, 
         contas.Key_User, 
         contas.Login_User,
         (
             SELECT
                 chat.Date
             FROM 
                 chat
             WHERE
                  (contatos.Key_User1 = chat.Key_User1 OR contatos.Key_User1 = chat.Key_User2)
             ORDER BY 
                  chat.Date DESC 
             LIMIT 1
         )  data_ultima_mensagem
   FROM contatos 
         INNER JOIN contas  ON (contatos.Key_User1 = contas.Key_User) 
   WHERE contas.Key_User not like 'valor'
   ORDER BY 
       data_ultima_mensagem
    ;
```

Neste caso, fiz uma subconsulta somente para saber qual é a data da Última mensagem.
Desta forma, não é necessário utilizar o group by.